# Screwed up lightdm file and am now in login loop

Tags: permissions, login, lightdm

Upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04...upgrade worked but ran into permission problems mounting usb stick and launching applications.
Attempting to fix this I edited and saved lightdm....am now stuck in login loop when I attempt to login using owner account...only other account is guest which allows login but has no permissions .....how can I re-edit lightdm file  to remove my changes using the guest account?

Answer (score 1):

Login using the TTYs: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>F1</kbd>to<kbd>F6</kbd>) to get to a login prompt, login, then use `sudo nano` to edit the configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do that is by reconfigure lightdm using dpkg:

so open a Terminal TTY   **Ctrl+Alt+F2** and do the folowing;

stop lightdm  `sudo service lightdm stop`

reconfigure   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

start lightdm `sudo service lightdm start`

it shoultd work fine if not move to the hard way by trying to undo by urself the changes of lightdm configuration you'll find it in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` good luck

and you may also check the permissions of lightdm or your profile (chown)